# jodit-angular paste the image copy from outlook will be cropped

Tags: angular, image, outlook, copy-paste, jodit

Here is a step-by-step **Tutorial** reproduce this issue:

1. Copy the image from Outlook E-Mail
   [Screenshot of Outlook Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ynS.jpg)
2. Use Ctrl + V to paste the image to the `Jodit editor`.
   [Image inside Jodit Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ormrT.png)
3. The image should not be cropped.

jodit-angular version: "1.11.1"

**Configuration:**
askBeforePasteFromWord: false,
processPasteFromWord: true,
defaultActionOnPasteFromWord: 'insert_clear_html',
pasteFromWord: {
enable: true,
convertUnitsToPixel: true
},
beautifyHTML: false,
askBeforePasteHTML: false,
enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
uploader: {
insertImageAsBase64URI: true
},